# MovieClip wont click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to AS3 so i formed the set of code with the help from examples and other people. I am trying to add a box(movieclip) that contains some Vector inside, and when the vectors are added from JSON data, the box are added on stage, and when clicked it goes to the next as file.

At the moment i got the code that counts the Vector's length, if the length is >0 it goes to the next page, if the length is 0 it does something else.
But for some reason, the movieclip when clicked, doesn't do anything.

Code that add the button

```
if( s3.listings.length > 0 )
        {
            // get the first listing in the listing array
            var newListing:Listing8 = s3.listings[0];
            newListing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscener);
        }
        else
        {

//

        }
```

Below are all the code
The searchVO1 takes in the JSON, send it over to SearchVectorTest,sresultnologin holds the SearchVectorTest for display inside the background image,the button is inside sresultnologin.

SearchVO1

```
package com.clark
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;



       public class searchVO1 extends MovieClip {
        private var Arvariables:URLVariables;
        private var SrSend:URLRequest;
        private var SaLoader:URLLoader;
           public var nobed:String;
        public var zip:String;
        public var Location:String;
        public var price:String;
           public var callMethod:Function;

public var s1:searchpage = new searchpage ();

               public function searchVO1():void{

addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);                  // init
function onadded (event:Event):void{


            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);
             s1.account.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToaccount);
             s1.searchs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ValidateAndsearch);
            s1.Au.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToautomatch);
            s1.setting.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToss);
            s1.Shome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTohom);




            // Build the varSend variable
            SrSend = new URLRequest("http://localhost/search.php");
            SrSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
                   Arvariables = new URLVariables;
            SrSend.data = Arvariables;

            SaLoader = new URLLoader();
            SaLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            SaLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Asandler);


 // private methods

           function Asandler(event:Event):void{

 // retrieve data from php call
var resultString :String = event.target.data;
// parse result string as json object and cast it to array
var resultArray  :Array  = JSON.parse( resultString ) as Array;
// get the length of the result set
var len:int = resultArray.length;

// create vector of SearchVO
var searchVOs:Vector.<searchVO1> = new Vector.<searchVO1>();
// loop the result array
               var i:int;
for(i=0; i<len; i++ )
{
    searchVOs[i] = new searchVO1();   
    searchVOs[i].nobed = resultArray[i].nobed;
    searchVOs[i].zip = resultArray[i].zip;
    searchVOs[i].Location = resultArray[i].Location;
    searchVOs[i].price =  resultArray[i].price;
}

// call a function to create your boxes

// or maybe create your SearchVector class and pass it your search vector
var mySearchVector:SearchVectorTest = new SearchVectorTest(searchVOs);
addChild(mySearchVector);
       }   
   }
   }

    public function searchVOs( nobed:String, zip:String, location:String, price:String )
        {
            this.nobed      = nobed;
            this.zip        = zip;
            this.Location   = Location;
            this.price      = price;
        }
        public function ValidateAndsearch (event:MouseEvent):void {

        // validate fields

         Arvariables.nobed = s1.nobed.text;
        Arvariables.zip = s1.zip.text;
            Arvariables.Location = s1.Location.text;
            Arvariables.price = s1.price.text;
    SaLoader.load(SrSend);
            var s7:sresultnologin = new sresultnologin()    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);




        }
         // close else condition for error handling

         // close validate and send function





        private function fl_ClickToGoToautomatch(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var s7:Auto = new Auto ();  
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);
        }

        private function fl_ClickToGoToss(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //
        }
        private function fl_ClickToGoToaccount(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var s7:Account = new Account ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);
        }



        private function fl_ClickToGoTohom(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s7:homepage = new homepage ();  
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s7);

        }


       }

}
```

SearchVectorTest

```
package  com.clark
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class SearchVectorTest extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var listings:Vector.<Listing8>;

        public function SearchVectorTest(test:Vector.<searchVO1>) 
        {

                for (var j:int = 0; j < test.length; j++) 
            {


                trace(test[j].nobed);
                trace(test[j].zip);
                trace(test[j].Location);
                trace(test[j].price);

        }

            var len:int = test ? test.length : 0;

         listings = new Vector.<Listing8>(len, true);
            var currentY:int = 100;

            for (var k:int = 0; k < test.length; k++) 
            {
                var Bolder:Listing8 = new Listing8();

                Bolder.x=20;

                var bf:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf1:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf2:TextField = new TextField();
                var bf3:TextField = new TextField();

                bf3.width = 100;
                bf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

                bf.width = 100;
                bf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf1.width = 100;
                bf1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                bf3.width = 100;
                bf1.y= bf.height+5;

                bf.text = test[k].nobed;
                bf1.text = test[k].zip;
                bf2.text = test[k].Location;
                bf3.text = test[k].price;

                bf.x = (Bolder.height-bf.height)*.2
                Bolder.addChild(bf);
                Bolder.addChild(bf1);
                Bolder.addChild(bf2);
                Bolder.addChild(bf3);
                Bolder.properties = test[k].nobed;
                Bolder.properties = test[k].zip;
    Bolder.y = currentY;

                addChild(Bolder);
                 Bolder.mouseChildren = false;    // ignore children mouseEvents
            Bolder.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
            Bolder.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
            Bolder.buttonMode = true; 

                 listings[k] = Bolder;
                currentY += Bolder.height + 10;
            }

        }


    }

}
```

sresultnologin

```
package com.clark

{
import com.clark.SearchVectorTest;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;




       public class sresultnologin extends MovieClip {

public var s1:Searchreult = new Searchreult ();

               public function sresultnologin(){
                  // init



            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);
         function onadded (event:Event):void{



            s1.x=-10;
            s1.y=10;

            addChild(s1);
         }

var s3:SearchVectorTest= new SearchVectorTest(new Vector.<searchVO1>);
                 addChild (s3);


            s1.SRhome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTol);
            s1.ARsearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGosearch);

 if( s3.listings.length > 0 )
        {
            // get the first listing in the listing array
            var newListing:Listing8 = s3.listings[0];
            newListing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscener);
        }
        else
        {

//

        }


           }

               // private methods
           private function gotoscener(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:Listingdetail = new Listingdetail ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);


       }


        private function fl_ClickToGoTol(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:Account = new Account ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);

        }

        private function fl_ClickToGosearch(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            var s9:searchVO1 = new searchVO1 ();    
    removeChild(s1);
            addChild(s9);


       }

}
}
```

Comment: Just an hypotesis: have you tried to remove bolder.mouseChildren from SearchVectorTest? The Listing8 movieClip is initially empty first to add the textfields? if yes you could try to add a shape to give it an hit area

Comment: Hi, i tried removing that, but it still doesn't click. And the Listing8 Movieclip has a green square box in it, and it is just a psd i loaded into the library.